# Intuitionistic logic and derivation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, sequent-calculus

It is my first approach to intuitionistic logic (IL) and, even if I understand the principle behind it, I struggle understanding when a sequent is derivable in IL and when is not. I know that IL allows only one formula "on the right" of the sequent " ⊢ ". But then I also know that:

$A \land B \vdash \lnot (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)$    is derivable in IL

$\lnot(\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \vdash A \land B$   is not derivable in IL

Why is this the case? Why the first sequent has only one formula to the right and the second sequent has more than one?

Comment: The second sequence also has *one* formula on the right, which is a conjunction $A\land B$.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that multiple formulas on the right (which, as Berci states, is *not* what's happening here) are usually joined disjunctively.

Comment: I'll try to explain me better. I had this exercise: Only one of the following sequents is derivable in Intuitionistic Logic:
exhibit a derivation of it in G.IL. A ∧ B ↔  ¬(¬A ∨ ¬B)  (where ↔ is intended as the "both direction sequent". It follows we have 2 statement to prove. The solution was that only A ∧ B ⊢ ¬(¬A ∨ ¬B) is derivable. I'm trying to understand why

Comment: Which are the inference rules of your intuitionistic derivation system? If you list them we can give you a precise answer.

Comment: I wrongly assumed that the problem was the initial count of formula after the sequent thinking that the first expression had count = 1 and the second one count > 1. But I see right now that the problem occurs during the actual proof of the expression. Where we end up with statement of this type ¬¬A⊢A that is not provable in an IL environment  by the non-application of the law of excluded middle

Comment: Indeed, it is not about the sequent calculus. Intuitionistic Logic accepts most of the rules of inference that build Classical Logic, with the *exceptions* being the Law of Excluded Middle and its coprovable rules. *This means that you may introduce negation, but cannot eliminate double negations.* So most classical equivalences can only be constructively proven in one direction of entailment.

Answer (score 3):

It might help to develop your intuitions(!) here if you first consider how we derive $A$ from  $\neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)$ in a *classical* natural deduction framework.

The obvious line of proof goes like this:

$\quad \neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)\\ 
\quad \quad \quad | \quad \neg A \\
\quad \quad \quad | \quad (\neg A \lor \neg B)\\
\quad \quad \quad | \quad \bot \\
\quad \neg\neg A\\
\quad A$

But ahah! *The last step is inadmissible in intuitionistic logic*, and so the proof fails there. We can't derive $A$ in intuitionistic logic (nor can we derive $B$, nor a fortiori their conjunction). We can derive $(\neg\neg A \land \neg\neg B)$ but can't get rid of the dratted double negations.

Comment: I think I got it. Even because we couldn't "move" the formula ¬(¬A∨¬B) to the right of the sequent because otherwise we end up with two formula to the right, like this:  ⊥ ⊢ A ∧ B, (¬A ∨ ¬B) that is not admissible. Is that right?

Comment: Think about why you can't prove $\neg \neg A \vdash A$ in your favoured intuitionist sequent calculus ...

Comment: I know that you can't prove it because we assume using IL that the "tertium non datur" or "middle excluded" it's not true. so we cannot prove ¬¬A⊢A.

Comment: Yes. The law of excluded middle and rule of double negation elimination are coprovable: you can prove one if and only if you admit the other. @CraigMontevecchi